# Align polygon triangle to bottom of div

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, responsive

I have a triangle polygon but there is a problem, I want to place it right above the 'onebysign' div but positioning is not working, it also has to stay responsive so when I change the screen size the polygon stays at his place.

So basically: I want the polygon triangle div to 'connect' with the 'onebysign' (something) div, it has to stay responsive and not move when the screen width is changed.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fmg6orkd/

HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.events {
  padding: 20px 100px;
}

.textInfo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #085DAD;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.onebyone {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
  position: relative;
  /* If you want text inside of it */
  background-size: cover;
}

.onebytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
}

.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.onebytext,
.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.submitBtn {
  background-color: #0099CC;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row events">
  <div class="onebyone">
    <div class="onebytext">
      <div class="textInfo">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle" data-type="vertical_parallax" data-speed="2">
      <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="410" height="410" viewBox="0 0 310 310">
                <polyline fill="#CC0000" points="0,0 0,20 310,20" />
              </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="onebysign">
      <button class="submitBtn">Something</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fmg6orkd/1/) ?

Comment: @Pedram not really, I want the triangle to connect with the other red DIV and still be responsive

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fmg6orkd/2/) But you can't make this example responsive because you used `absolute` position many times on each section. You should re-code it.

Comment: @Pedram Yeah I already tried your solution indeed, but I thought maybe there was a way to fix it without having to recode the entire thing :)

Comment: Actually it so hard to make `absolute` container and elements inside it *responsive*, I recommend you to re-code.

Comment: @Pedram I'll just try it and come back here when I figured it out, for now I just keep this thread open just in case someone does come up with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to remove width/height from svg and adjust the viewbox to cover the needed part of the polygon, then you can easily use postioning:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.events {
  padding: 20px 100px;
}

.textInfo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #085DAD;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.onebyone {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
  position: relative;
  /* If you want text inside of it */
  background-size: cover;
}

.onebytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
}

.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.onebytext,
.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.submitBtn {
  background-color: #0099CC;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 51px;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row events">
  <div class="onebyone">
    <div class="onebytext">
      <div class="textInfo">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle" data-type="vertical_parallax" data-speed="2">
      <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 310 20">
                <polyline fill="#CC0000" points="0,0 0,20 310,20" />
              </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="onebysign">
      <button class="submitBtn">Something</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to use pseudo element with linear-gradient background in order to create the triangle and you will have less HTML code to manage:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.events {
  padding: 20px 100px;
}

.textInfo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #085DAD;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.onebyone {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
  position: relative;
  /* If you want text inside of it */
  background-size: cover;
}

.onebytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
}

.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.onebytext,
.onebysign {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.submitBtn {
  background-color: #0099CC;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.onebysign:before {
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, red 47%, transparent 50%);
    left: 0;
    top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row events">
  <div class="onebyone">
    <div class="onebytext">
      <div class="textInfo">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="onebysign">
      <button class="submitBtn">Something</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a hero! Been struggling for this for so long but this works perfect, the 2nd solution indeed worked best for me. Thanks! :)